# Make Google Full Row Number Drop Down List

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I want to use the Google Apps script to put all the row numbers in the active sheet in the drop-down list.
What I want to do is like this.

[image]

But my current results are like this.

[image]

What should I do? I need help.
This is my current code.

```
function getRowNum() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var arr =[];
 var rowArr = [];
 for(var i=1;i<ss.getMaxRows();i++){
    arr.push(i);
    rowArr.push(arr.slice(arr.length-1));
    var options = `<option value="${rowArr}">${rowArr}</option>`;  
  }
   var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('sidebar');
   html.options = options;
   var h = html.evaluate()
      .setTitle('MySidebar')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(h);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, `rowArr` has all values like `[[1], [2],,,]`. By this, your situation occurs. I think that this is the reason for your issue. In order to achieve your goal, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var arr =[];
var rowArr = [];
for(var i=1;i<ss.getMaxRows();i++){
   arr.push(i);
   rowArr.push(arr.slice(arr.length-1));
   var options = `<option value="${rowArr}">${rowArr}</option>`;  
 }
```

#### To:

```
var options = "";
for (var i = 1; i < ss.getMaxRows(); i++) {
  options += `<option value="${i}">Row ${i}</option>`;
}
```

- In this case, it supposes taht your HTML side of `sidebar` is as follows.

  ```
    <select><?!= options ?></select>
  ```

Comment: It works exactly the way I want it to. Thanks a lot.